# How to confer residency rights without tenancy?

Tags: united-states, real-estate, massachusetts, tenant

I am buying a large house which has an existing owner who is a very old man and I would like to give him the right to continue to live in the house, but not have the same rights as a tenant (exclusive use). In other words, I would be able to say which rooms he could or could not use and so forth. So, he would be more like my guest than my tenant.

Is there some kind of legal status for a relationship like this?

Comment: Tenancy law is pretty state-dependent. What state?

Comment: I can't find positive info about Massachusetts, but in many places this is simply impossible - any person who lives in a place for long enough will automatically acquire the rights of a tenant, such as due process before eviction, and this can't be waived.  However, you might be able to rent him some rooms in the house, like a roommate - he'd be a tenant, but wouldn't have exclusive use of the whole house.